# iOS copy pasting texts from Pasteboard works fine some time, some time it disappears after some time in textview

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uipasteboard

I have implemented the copy paste from UI pasteboard and then displaying the first 300 characters. I disabled the emoji from copy paste.Problem only occurs some time on first time, after that it works fine. It works fine some time, but some time it pasted correct and after some time delete the pasted text.
Same issue in iOS 12,13.6

Here is my code:-

```
    func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        
                if let paste = UIPasteboard.general.string, text == paste {
                    print("paste")
                    if (textView.text + text).containsEmoji(){
                        return false
                    }else{
                        return true
                    }
               }
               return textView.text.count + (text.count - range.length) <= 300}
    
    
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView){
        if textView.text.count >= 300{
            let trimString = String(textView.text.prefix(300))
           textView.text = trimString
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the first 300 chars then your prefix function should take in '300' and not '320'...

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView){
    if textView.text.count >= 300{
        let trimString = String(textView.text.prefix(300)) // <- try this
       textView.text = trimString
    }
}
```

### Edit

Also, the last return statement in 'shouldChangeTextIn' should be false if you don't want to replace the string with something that doesn't match the pasteboard. That could be your problem.

Comment: I updated the last line in shouldChangeTextIn and also updated in the above code , it still didn't solve the problem.